# how make python command line apps accessible globally?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I wrote a command-line app using python.
the problem is I want the to user can use the command globally after installed the command-line .
I wrote the command-line, I published the package but I don't know how to make this package globally available for users as system commands.

Example :

```
pip install forosi
```

and after that user can globally run this command from everywhere they want . like :

```
forosi help
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have the main file you are supposed to run in `src/forosi.py` in your package directory, but you should be able to adapt this if it's different.

- First, you want to rename the script to `forosi`, without the `.py` extension.
- Second, at the top of the file (now called `forosi`) add the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

... rest of file...
```

- In your `setup.py` for the package, you need to use the `scripts` option.

```py
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    scripts=['src/forosi'],
    ...
)
```

---

This is the method that required minimal refactoring of your code. If you happen to have a `main()` function in one of your python files which is the entrypoint of the script, you can just add the following into your setup.py instead of the above:

```py
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['src.forosi:main'],
    }
    ...
)
```

---

In either case, to build the package locally, run

```
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

This will create a *wheel* file in the `dist/` directory called `package_name-version-<info>-.whl`. This is the official distribution for pypi packages.

To install this package, run:

```
pip3 install dist/package_name-version-<info>-.whl
```

or if you only have one version in the dist folder, just

```
pip3 install dist/*
```

Comment: Could you add instructions about installing such package locally?

Comment: what if my cli have 3 command ? like "forosi login" , "forosi logout"

Comment: @Phineas If you want to install locally, first run `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` and then `pip3 install dist/*`.

Comment: @TokyoDeveloper In this case you're going to have to make your `forosi` script handle arguments. I suggest looking into [argparse subcommands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)

Comment: I think it would be useful to add the installation instructions to your answer